# Orchard CMS (Legacy 1.10, not the Core one) Permalink not found on multiple web server

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.10

I have an issue with Permalink.
Let me explain my current server topology as below :

I have two web servers (1 for CMS, 1 for Content Delivery) and single database. Both servers connect to same database server. The purpose of separate web servers is, CMS server only serve admin / content authoring, and the other is for public serving (can not access admin page).

The issue is,
when I create a content from CMS server, I could access the content using its permalink from the server.
But, when I tried to accessed it from Content Delivery server by its permalink, it shows Not Found page.
When I tried to access from Content Delivery server by its content display Url (like *"/Contents/Item/Display/27"*), it works.

Another weird behavior is, when I tried to get Url of the new created content programmatically using  `UrlHelper.ItemDisplayUrl()` upon `IContentManager.Query` result, it return the content display Url instead of Permalink one (while the older contents returned permalink url).

But, If I do an IIS reset on my Content Delivery Server, the permalink will works. Please help.

For additional information : I installed Orchard Cache module.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a normal behavior. Since the CD instance is not signaled that a new content item is created, it keeps serving the context that it is already cached.
So, you have to invalidate the context of CD server so as to request a fresh copy from database.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your lead. I thought because we used the same database that would be no issue (my assumption is that if the requested URL doesn't found in cache, then it should take a look into the database). Could you guide me more about how to signal the CD server?

Comment: I dig around and found "Distributed Signals" feature that specify "Distribute signals cache invalidation calls.", but found no documentations related to it. I tried to enable "Message Bus", "SQL Server Service Broker" and "Distributed Signals" features and retry the case, but it doesn't solve my issue. Also, there's no configuration menu on admin page regarding this (to configure which target server to sync or something like that). Is this the correct features to handle multi instance Orchard? how to use it?